# An old fashioned word or phrase that describes a meditative walk

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, nouns

An old fashioned word or phrase that describes a meditative walk. It's not a constitutional
but it's something that Ben Franklin, or Thomas Edison would do to clear their mind, rejuvenate, reconnect, invigorate, rebalance etc. I think there is a noun for this activity. They might say "I am going to take my ...."

Answer (score 6):

How about:

- Ramble
- Constitutional
- Meander
- Stroll

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the word you are looking for is *[perambulation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/perambulation)*. The verb *perambulate* is defined as:-

> v.tr.
>
> 1. To walk through.
> 2. To inspect (an area) on foot.
>
> v.intr.
>
> To walk about; roam or stroll.

so the third meaning turned into the noun form would be quite close to what you want.

Answer (score 4):

**Kinhin** is the walking meditation that is practiced between long periods of the sitting meditation known as zazen.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinhin

Answer (score 1):

I doubt Ben Franklin or Thomas Edison used this term, but there is the Australian word *walkabout*, which [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/walkabout) defines as:

> a short period of wandering bush life engaged in by an Australian aborigine as an occasional interruption of regular work — often used in the phrase go walkabout

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take the word *jaunt* and attach an adjective of your choosing to it.

> - an invigorating jaunt
> - a meditative jaunt
> - a refreshing jaunt
> - a mind-clearing jaunt
> - a re-balancing jaunt
> - a re-centering jaunt

*Jaunt*, by itself, suggests a pleasurable walk or perambulation; by combining it with an adjective you conjoin pleasure with mental refreshment.

Answer (score 0):

It's also called ***mindful walking*** and the context can be found [*here*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mindfulness_(psychology))

Also consider 'I am going to take my ***ritual walk***'.

You could replace *walk* with other suggested synonymous words.

It's also common to say ***refreshing walk*** as in a 'long and refreshing walk'.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase ["morning constitutional"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13717/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-phrase-the-morning-constitutional) brings victorian gentlemen walking in Hyde Park to my mind.